# Django Elastic Beanstalk Cron job

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, cron

I am trying to create a simple cron to send email. I searched and tried different answers but none of them seem to be working.

This is my django.config

It is one of the answer i found on net.

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py migrate --noinput"
    leader_only: true
  02_cronjb:
    command: "cat .ebextensions/cronjobs.cron > /etc/cron.d/djangocrons && chmod 644 /etc/cron.d/djangocrons"
    leader_only: true
  03_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: github.settings
    PYTHONPATH: $PYTHONPATH
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: github.wsgi:application
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    /static/: www/static/
packages:
  yum:
    postgresql95-devel: []
```

This is cronjobs.cron

```
* * * * * root source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && /opt/python/run/venv/bin/python /opt/python/current/github/manage.py cronjb >> /var/log/cronjobs.log
```

This is my cronjb.py

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand
from django.core.mail import send_mail



class Command(BaseCommand):

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        subject = 'Hello'
        message = 'World'
        email_from = "abc@gmail.come"
        recipient_list = ['abc@gmail.com']
        send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list)
```

It all gets deployed without any error but the i am not receiving any emails.

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Have you checked /var/log/cronjobs.log? Also are you using amazon linux 1 or 2?

Comment: here are the logs:https://filebin.net/4qq2txi5txdo5y44/log.txt?t=lxq3w8r7 and i am using linux 2.9.14

Comment: When you ssh into the instance, and manually run the cronjb.py, does it work? In other words, is the issue only limited to automated deployment and if you do things manually on the instance, there are no issues?

Comment: when i try to do python cronjb.py it shows error like could not find from django.core.management.base, but it is same on other custom commands but other are working. And now i tried ```04_cronjb:
    command: "* * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && cd /opt/python/current/app/ && python manage.py cronjb > $HOME/cron-sqs.log 2>&1"
    leader_only: true``` in the django.config and now if i try to deploy it shows an error ``` Command failed on instance. Return code: 127 Output: /bin/sh: 2.jpg: command not found.```. I don't know why it is showing 2.jpg

Comment: 2.jpg is a file at root of my project where .ebextensions folder are located. But i don't know why is it showing that.